# Problemas con fscanf en C

Tags: c

Buenas noches, tengo un problema al usar fscanf para leer unos datos de un archivo de entrada, el problema es que por ninguna forma lee el archivo, este es el fragmento de código

```
FILE  *infile = NULL;
FILE  *outfile=NULL;

infile  = fopen("mtbank.in",  "r");
outfile = fopen("mtbank.out", "w");


char prueba[80];
fscanf(infile,"%s",&prueba);
printf("esto es una %s",prueba);
```

como resultado obtiene:

```
esto es una °]¾
```

Como puedo solucionar esto? Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que estás colocando un & antes de prueba en la función fscanf.

Así debería funcionar correctamente.

```
fscanf(infile,"%s",prueba);
```

Recuerda que prueba es un vector y por lo tanto, también es un puntero al comienzo de dicho vector (es decir, su dirección de memoria), es por esto que no debes colocar el &.